# Merging AVL trees using an empty tree (C++ templates)

Tags: c++, data-structures, merge, binary-tree, avl-tree

As part of an AVL template I am working on (C++ templates) I was trying to merge 2 AVL trees in O(n1+n2) complexity when n1+n2 is the total elements in both trees.

I thought about the next algorithm.

1. Inorder traversal on the 1st tree and build an array/list - O(n1)
2. Inorder traversal on the 2nd tree and build an array/list - O(n2)
3. Merge sort of those 2 arrays and build final sorted array/list in the size of n1+n2 - O(n1+n2)
4. Build an empty almost complete binary tree with n1+n2 vertices - O(n1+n2).
5. Inorder traversal on that almost complete binary tree while updating the vertices with the elemets in the merged array/list.

My question is how do I actually build the **empty almost complete binary tree with n1+n2 vertices**?

Comment: Note that if your tree supports iterators like those in the [standard binary tree container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html), you can actually perform step 3 directly without copying the two trees' nodes in intermediate storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nodes issue by the merge sort are stored in a vector, it can be done relatively easily.  Your nodes are already sorted, so you can "insert" the nodes in the following fashion:

1. Build your root node from the element at 1/2 of the array;
2. Build the root's child nodes using the elements at 1/4 and 3/4 of the array;
3. Repeat 2 recursively.

This should feel to you as an in-order traversal of a binary tree that happens to be represented as a sorted array.

Note that for this to work, you need to build the tree with balancing "turned off".  This is most likely going to require you to make this a private method of your class, probably a special constructor.

Comment: By the way, this is more like steps 4 and 5 combined.  I don't suggest you build the "empty binary tree with `n1+n2` nodes".

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. I guess it's considered to be more simple than just building an almost complete tree with X elements? Also, each vertex in my tree contains a field which says how many elements there are in the left sub-tree. If building the tree this way I'll have to update all those fields in an inorder traversal  after the tree is already done?

Comment: When you split the array, you know how many nodes you're going to insert on either side, even though you haven't inserted the child nodes yet.  Either set it to that value, or actually perform the insertion recursively and sum up the child nodes on the way back up